# Will I get in trouble for applying directly to a company when a recruiter previously put me forward for a different position?

Tags: recruitment, united-kingdom

A recruiter put me forward for a position several months ago, and I never heard back. I'd seen the job ad around and I believe he probably put my CV forward quite late in the process when they'd already filled or nearly filled the position. The recruiter never heard back from the hiring manager, and he eventually also stopped replying to my messages.

Two months later, that same company put up a job ad for a slightly different position (but in the same team so presumably the hiring manager was the same), and I applied directly and got the job, which I've now started.

I'd completely forgotten about that previous job application (as I had lots of ongoing applications at the time and this one never progressed), but stumbled upon those messages as I was going through my old texts.

Could I/the company get in trouble for handling my application as if I'd applied directly when the hiring manager technically already had my CV from the recruiter? Should I tell someone at the company about this?

Comment: To give them a heads up so they can deal with it proactively? I'm assuming they never actually looked at my CV the first time round because they'd already filled the role, so are unaware that this might come up.

Answer (score 3):

Will you get into trouble? No.

A problem may arise if the recruiter has a time based contract with the company for any candidates they put forward.  This would mean the company has to pay the recruiter even though you applied directly.

To be honest, it's not your job to worry about it.  I'd just forget about it